# Using the Stencil Buffer to cut out windows

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, stencil-buffer

I am trying to use the stencil buffer to cut two windows in a solid box. The windows are two rectangles (composed of 2 triangles).

But the OpenGL stencil buffer flags seem difficult to decipher.

Here is what I am doing

```
glClearStencil(0.0f);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
glStencilMask(0xFF); 
         DrawWindows();

glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF); 
glStencilMask(0x00); 
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
         DrawSolidBox();
```

However, this just give me a constant cutout in the box, on both sides, where I only want the windows to be cut out on the side where they are co-planer with the one wall

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. You never clear the stencil buffer (`glClearStencil` doesn't do that), you disable the stencil test before drawing the box. But I've still no idea what you are _trying_ to achieve. The descriptions about "windows" and "walls" are not really understandable for someone who doesn't know your scene.

Comment: basically I have to vertex arrays one with windows and one with walls

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: not really sure how or what you mean ... I basically have a solid box and trying to produce cut-outs in the box .. and trying to use the stencil/depth buffer to do it, but failing

Comment: if you want ot stencil out something on a single face, you have to enable the stencil test when drawing that particular face only. You caan;t draw a whole box and expect that the GL magicaluesses which faces should be affected by the test and which shouldn't.

Comment: I understand what you were trying to do, it's pretty obvious, did you have any luck with this approach?